# How to delete the content of the two cells to the right if active cell meets criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have written the following code to input the date in the cell to the right if the active cell = 'yes' or 'no'. This part of the code is working but when the active cell doesn't meet the criteria then I want it to clear the content of the two cells to the right.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will cause an input
'date and time in next 2 cells to the right when active cell is changed.

Set KeyCells = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("VW_P1_P2").ListColumns("C1 Made Contact?").Range

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
  Is Nothing Then

If Target = "Yes" Or Target = "No" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 2).Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm")
Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 2).ClearContents
End If

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues/improvements:

- Use `Me` to refer to the parent worksheet, instead of `ActiveSheet`.
- Avoid using `ActiveCell`, and instead use `Target` to refer to the changed cell(s).
- `Range(Target.Address)` is redundant.  Just use `Target`.
- If `Target` is a multi-cell range, you can't compare it to `"Yes"` or `"No"`, so use a loop.
- You're changing the sheet programmatically, so best practice would be to temporarily disable events, and re-enable them at the end.
- I'd suggest using `.ListColumns("C1 Made Contact?").DataBodyRange` instead of `.ListColumns("C1 Made Contact?").Range`. This would exclude the column header `C1 Made Contact`.
- Instead of `Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")`, you could just use `Date`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will cause an input
    'date and time in next 2 cells to the right when active cell is changed.
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Me.ListObjects("VW_P1_P2").ListColumns("C1 Made Contact?").DataBodyRange

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
       On Error GoTo SafeExit
       Application.EnableEvents = False

       Dim cell As Range
       For Each cell in rng
           If cell.Value = "Yes" Or cell.Value = "No" Then
               cell.Offset(-1, 1).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy") ' or just Date
               cell.Offset(-1, 2).Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm")
           Else
               cell.Offset(-1, 1).ClearContents
               cell.Offset(-1, 2).ClearContents
           End If
       Next
    End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:

If `KeyCells` is multiple columns in your table, then you could use `Union`:

```
With Me.ListObjects("VW_P1_P2")
   Dim KeyCells As Range
   Set KeyCells = Union(.ListColumns("C1 Made Contact?").DataBodyRange, _
                        .ListColumns("C2 Made Contact?").DataBodyRange, _
                        .ListColumns("C3 Made Contact?").DataBodyRange)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance works a treat. If I wanted to apply this to 2 other columns could I use an 'or' on the keycells? for example agents make multiple attempts to contact a customer so there is a column called  'C2 Made Contact?' & 'C3 Made Contact?'. would this work?